# Cleaning up a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database with hundreds of tables.

I am building a script to delete all of the rows in this database.

Of course, being a relational database, I have to delete rows from the children before I can touch the parents.

Is there something I can use for this or do I have to do this the hard way?

**EDIT**

***Accepted Answer was modified to include Disable Trigger as well***

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON ? '
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?'
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ENABLE TRIGGER ALL ON ? '
```

Comment: I want the structure.. just not the data. I dont really want to drop it all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable all the constraints, then delete all the data, and enable the constraints again. You can put the code in a stored procedure for reutilization. Something quick and dirty:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_EmplyAllTable
AS
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable ‘ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL’
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable ‘DELETE FROM ?’
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable ‘ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL’
GO
```

Comment: And.. depending of the database, maybe we could want to disable/enable all the triggers using the same syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you want the structure without any of the data?

Can you script the tables / sp's / user-defined functions / triggers / permissions etc. and then drop the database before recreating it with the script?

This link explains how to generate a script for all the objects in a database using SQL server Management studio... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078.aspx

Comment: Scripting the DB and dropping/recreating is definitely the the easiest and quickest way to go

Comment: Actually, it is more complicated than other approaches. Firstly, you have the retrieval of the script objects themselves. secondly you have to maintain your repository of scripts and roles and permissions. a generic script to loop through table objects and drop data is far more simple

Comment: Agreed.  Scripting metadata is nasty business.  Easier just to delete the data.

Comment: @Jason Irwin: I agree. This database is in a continuous state of flux, so I would have to rescript every time I went through this.

Comment: Using the script wizard as per my link is a case of: Select the database -> check to include all objects -> Next -> Next ->Script to File -> Next -> Finish. Not really what I'd call 'complicated' or 'a nasty business', but each to his own. @Raj More you would have to re-script every time, but if the database is constantly changing, you might have to rewrite your script every time too?

Answer (score 2):

If this were MySQL, I would use "`mysqldump --no-data`" to make a backup of the database metadata only.  Then I would drop the database entirely and restore my data-less backup.

In addition to being a three-step process, it is a lot faster just in terms of transactions and I/O than deleting from each table individually.  And it also shrinks the tablespace on disk, which deleting would not do (for InnoDB, that is).

I'm not familiar with Microsoft SQL Server's backup tools, is there some equivalent option?

---

I think I've found something promising:  [How to: Generate a Script (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078.aspx)

> To generate a script of an entire
>   database
>
> 1. In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the SQL Server Database
>      Engine and then expand that instance.
> 2. Expand **Databases**, right-click any database, point to **Tasks**, point to
>      **Generate Scripts**, and then follow the
>      steps in the **Generate Scripts Wizard**.

Comment: This feature is kind of a pain when there are ordering dependencies involved.  You would have to first script out all of the FKs, then script out all of the rest anfter changing the scripting options.  THis is one of the reasons that SQL Compare and other 3rd parties are so popular.  They handle Metadata complexity for you, where as SSMS and SSIS don't